# An Array to copy and paste from one sheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

New to Java scripting so looking for some help, I am designing a Holiday spreadsheet with two sheets

- a master sheet that contains each department’s team member’s (Sheet 4)
- a Holiday sheet so users can input their teams holidays (Sheet5).

I have found a script that will insert a row or delete a row in Sheet 4 and Sheet 5, but I now need a script that will copy the contents of a newly inserted Row in sheet 4 and paste the data over to newly inserted row in sheet 5 in the same row as sheet 4.

For example if I add a row say in A10 in sheet 4 and put a Capital “Y” in A10 I would like the data from B10 to I10 to copy over to sheet 5 in row A10 to NJ10. 
I tried to find a solution to this but I can’t get it to work using the Copyto command.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet5 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet5');
  var sheet4 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet4");
  var values1 = sheet4.getRange("A:A").getValues();
  var values2 = sheet4.getRange("A:A").getValues();
  var values3 = sheet4.getRange("A:A").getValues();
  // This starts off the remove and Insert Row Code
  var deleteRow = new Array(); // Part of remove and Insert Row Code
  var insertRow = new Array(); // Part of remove and Insert Row Code
  var copyPaste = new Array(); // Copies to Sheet5  
  for (var i = 0; i < values1.length; i++) {
    if (values1[i] == 'D') {
      deleteRow.push(i + 1); // This line was added for debugging purposes.
      var X = sheet4.getRange(i + 1, "2").getValues();
      var response = Browser.msgBox('WARNING!!  You are about to Delete the record for', X, Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
      Logger.log(response);
      if (response == "yes") {

      } else {
        sheet4.getRange('A:A').clearContent();
        Browser.msgBox('Cancelled', 'The operation has been cancelled', Browser.Buttons.OK);
      }
    }
  }
  for (var i = deleteRow.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    sheet4.deleteRow(deleteRow[i]);
  }
  for (var i = deleteRow.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    sheet5.deleteRow(deleteRow[i]);
  }
  for (var k = 0; k < values2.length; k++) {
    if (values2[k] == 'I') {
      insertRow.push(k + 1); // This line was added for debugging purposes.        
      sheet4.getRange('A:A').clearContent(); //Removes "I" to stop code repeating
    }
  }

  for (var k = insertRow.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
    sheet4.insertRowAfter(insertRow[k]);
  }
  for (var k = insertRow.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
    sheet5.insertRowAfter(insertRow[k]);
  }
  for (var m = 0; m < values3.length; m++) {
    if (values3[m] == 'Y') {
      copyPaste.push(m + 1); // This line was added for debugging    purposes.        
      sheet4.getRange('A:A').clearContent(); //Removes "Y" to stop code repeating
    }
  }
  for (var m = copyPaste.length - 1; m >= 0; m--) {
    sheet4.copyTo('B2:I13')(copyPaste[m]);
  }
  for (var m = copyPaste.length - 1; m >= 0; m--) {
    sheet4.copyTo('B2:J13')(copyPaste[m]);
  }
}
 //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

function onEdit(e) {
 // so 56930421_04
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var mastername = "Sheet4";
  var master = ss.getSheetByName(mastername);
  var hols = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet5');

  // get the range for Master and the data also
  var masterLR = master.getLastRow();
  var masterRange = master.getRange(4,2,masterLR-3,8);
  Logger.log("DEBUG: MASTER range = "+masterRange.getA1Notation());
  var masterData = masterRange.getValues();

  // get the last Column for hols for use in setting the update range
  var holsLC = hols.getLastColumn();
   Logger.log("DEBUG: the last column on Hols = "+holsLC);

  // display event objects - two mwthods displayed here
  // Method#1
   Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))

  // Method#2
  // var debug_e = {authMode:  e.authMode,range:  e.range.getA1Notation(),source:  e.source.getId(),user:  e.user,value:  e.value,oldValue: e. oldValue};
   //Logger.log("DEBUG: AuthMode: "+debug_e.authMode+", Range: "+debug_e.range+", source: "+debug_e.source+", user: "+debug_e.user+", value: "+debug_e.value+", old value: "+debug_e.oldValue);

  // get the column, row and sheet name of the edited cell
  var editColumn = e.range.getColumn();
  var editRow = e.range.getRow();
  var editSheet = e.range.getSheet().getSheetName();
  Logger.log("DEBUG: editted Column = "+editColumn+", editted Row = "+editRow+", edited Sheet = "+editSheet);

  // set variable
  var firstdatarow = 4;

  // create if statement
  // iF the edited row is between firstdatarow and the last row
  // AND
  // IF the edited column is Column#1  (Column A)
  // AND
  // IF the edited sheet is Master
  if (firstdatarow < editRow && editRow < masterLR && editColumn == 1 && e.value == "Y" && editSheet == mastername) {

    // do something
     Logger.log("DEBUG: do something");

    // get the employee name
    var empname = masterData[(+editRow-4)][0];
    Logger.log("DEBUG: The employee name is "+empname);


    // create an alert to confirm
    var result = ui.alert(
      'WARNING!!  You are about to Update the holiday record for '+empname,
      'Are you sure you want to continue?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

    // Process the user's response.
    if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
      // User clicked "Yes".
      ui.alert('Confirmation received.');


      // build the data to be pasted to Sheet5
      var holsData = [];
      for (var i = 1; i<54;i++){ 
        for (var x = 1; x<8;x++){
          holsData.push(masterData[(+editRow-1)][x]);
        }
        Logger.log("DEBUG: hols = "+holsData+", length = "+holsData.length);
      }
      Logger.log("DEBUG: Progressive holsData = "+holsData+", length = "+holsData.length);


      // create the range for Sheet5
      var target = hols.getRange(editRow,2,1,(+holsLC-1));
      Logger.log("DEBUG: the target range = "+target.getA1Notation());

      // update the values to Sheet5
      target.setValues([holsData]);

      //Removes "Y" to stop code repeating
      master.getRange(editRow,editColumn).clearContent();


    } else {

      // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
      ui.alert('Permission denied.');

      //Removes "Y" to stop code repeating
      master.getRange(editRow,editColumn).clearContent(); 
    }
  }
  else
  {
    // don't do anything
    Logger.log("don't do anything");
  }  
}
```

Comment: Might you have forgotten to mention what library you are using? For example PHPExcel. Doesnt look like youre using plain vsnilla js.

Comment: I haven't quite understood the code. 

But the if statements need to be changed.

Try:
values1[i][0] == 'D'
values2[k][0] == 'I'
values3[m][0] == 'Y'

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I am using Google Sheets for work Zim84 but very new to the coding side of the application.

Comment: ADW, I have made the changes to my IF Statements.  I think the problem is the last two For Loops, nothing copies over to Sheet5 but I also do not get an error message and the script does not crash.

Comment: Welcome. Would you please clarify some things? 1) "found a script that will insert a row or delete a row in Sheet 4 and Sheet 5" Is this the onEdit(e) in your question? 2) Do you use this  OnEdit(e), or is it intended as a basis for developing new code? E.g. the code deletes rows, would you confirm that you want to delete rows from "Sheet4"? 3) "data from B10 to I10 [copied to] sheet 5 in row A10 to NJ10". There are 8 columns between "B10" and "I10" but many more between "A10" and "NJ10". Please confirm the target range for "sheet5".

Comment: Notwithstanding my queries above, would you please share your spreadsheet (remove any private &/or confidential data). And would you include an example of how a successful outcome would appear.

Comment: Hi Tedinoz, for point One yes is onEdit, not fully understanding point Two but yes it currently does delete rows in sheet 4 and 5 and is working as intended.

Comment: Hi Tedinoz, for point One yes is onEdit, point Two but yes it currently does delete rows in sheet 4 and 5 and is working as intended.  Basically sheet 4 is a sheet that records a name in column B, C to I are the days of the week, so if for example a employee has Sun and Monday as their day off then Once the "Y" has been entered into column A, I would like the data for column B (the Employee Name) to copy over to sheet 5 in Column A, and the working week  B to I to copy over and repeat up to column NJ which will be the rest of the year, in the same row as in sheet 4.

Comment: Hi Tedinoz, As this project is for work I am not allowed to share this with you so I will create my own account at home and send from there.  Thanks for looking into this.  Col

Comment: @Colin Put an "@" sign in front of a users name, and your message will be automatically notified to them. Regarding: " and the working week B to I to copy over and repeat up to column NJ which will be the rest of the year, in the same row as in sheet 4." - that is not clear from your question. Please edit your question to add that information. Looking forward to your spreadsheet.

Comment: @Tedinoz  hi here is my spreadsheet, I hope its copied over correctly, If you can take a look at it that would be appreciated.  Sheet 5 is how I would like the copied date from sheet 4 to look. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-8szR-GK_BlctqIOCXo6eqhXSMCOe2MkZXsnQfj3bKc/edit#gid=0

Comment: May I clarify - please correct me if I'm wrong. 1) No data/rows are deleted from Sheet4 (except for the temporary input in Column A) 2) Every employee name in Column B of Sheet4, is repeated in Column A of Sheet5 and on the same row number as in Sheet4. 3) If "Y" is entered in Column A of Sheet4 (between row#4 and the last row of content) then the data for the employee (Column B) on that row from columns C to I (inclusive) is to be copied to the relevant employee row of Sheet5 in columns B to H (inclusive) AND repeated a further 52 times on the same row (one for each week of the year).

Comment: Clarification regarding Regarding Sheet5 - again please correct me. You said the data should be repeated on Sheet5 up to Column NJ. Since Column NJ represents a Monday, you mean that the data should be repeated up to but **excluding** column NJ.

Comment: @Tedinoz Hi yes you are correct that's exactly what I need if its possible.  I made a slight change to the spreadsheet so yes up to but excluding column NJ.  Thanks again for looking into this for me.  Col

Comment: @Tedinoz Hi It does not seem to work, when I put in a Capital Y in column A in Sheet 4 I get the two alerts but nothing copies over to Sheet5, the Capital Y in Sheet4 also stays in column A.  if I click no to the second alert the capital Y does clear.
Any ideas to what has gone wrong.


Thanks Col

Comment: @Colin Please check the Execution transcript. If the script failed, please copy paste the transcript into your question. Where are you in the world? I am in Sydney; I think we should continue in chat.

Comment: Would you please edit your question to insert your new code? Don't delete the old code-insert a Horizontal Rule and insert the new code below that. Would you also please check the **exact** spelling of your 'Sheet4' and 'Sheet5' and compare to the rows 6 and 8 of the code. Lastly, would you please uncomment the Logger statements on rows 13, 18, 22, 32, 46, 50, 71, 73, 78; then insert Cap "Y" as before; view the Logs, and copy/paste the logs into your question. @Colin, can we email via Anita at Baxter?

Comment: @Tedinoz I am in the UK, I will do as you suggest and get back to you by 09:00 GMT tomorrow. yes email as above, thanks again Col

Comment: I get the Error message
ReferenceError:"e"Is not defined.(line 76.file"code")

the code with this is
Logger.Log(JSON.stringify(e))

I have sent you an email with a picture.
Thanks col

Comment: @Colin OPen your Hols spreadsheet and we'll chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Event objects** Though you elected to use an `onEdit` trigger, you didn't use any of the event objects automatically generated by the `onEdit()`. This would have allowed you to simplify your code and create a definitive `IF` statement to validate whether "Y" was entered in the correct column, row, and sheet.

**Code development** You evidently re-defined your goals as you developed your code; including (eventually) unnecessary steps to delete, insert and append rows. This had the effect of complicating your code, for example the three identical variables created for `sheet4.getRange("A:A").getValues();`

**Pushing array values** You hit upon the right strategy to update "Sheet5" when you began to push values onto a temporary array. In this answer, I created two nested loops to build the necessary values. The first loops for 53 weeks and the second loops for 7 days - so the array is built up a week at a time for 53 weeks.

The code described in this answer is just one approach. There are likely to be other ways for you to achieve your goal. I've also left a number of `Logger.log()` statements in the code; you may wish to use these identify values at different stages of the function.

---

```
function onEdit(e) {

  // so 56930421_04
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var mastername = "Sheet4";
  var master = ss.getSheetByName(mastername);
  var hols = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet5');

  // get the range for Master and the data also
  var masterLR = master.getLastRow();
  var masterRange = master.getRange(4,2,masterLR-3,8);
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: MASTER range = "+masterRange.getA1Notation());
  var masterData = masterRange.getValues();

  // get the last Column for hols for use in setting the update range
  var holsLC = hols.getLastColumn();
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the last column on Hols = "+holsLC);

  // display event objects - two mwthods displayed here
  // Method#1
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))

  // Method#2
  // var debug_e = {authMode:  e.authMode,range:  e.range.getA1Notation(),source:  e.source.getId(),user:  e.user,value:  e.value,oldValue: e. oldValue};
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: AuthMode: "+debug_e.authMode+", Range: "+debug_e.range+", source: "+debug_e.source+", user: "+debug_e.user+", value: "+debug_e.value+", old value: "+debug_e.oldValue);

  // get the column, row and sheet name of the edited cell
  var editColumn = e.range.getColumn();
  var editRow = e.range.getRow();
  var editSheet = e.range.getSheet().getSheetName();
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: editted Column = "+editColumn+", editted Row = "+editRow+", edited Sheet = "+editSheet);

  // set variable
  var firstdatarow = 4;

  // create if statement
  // iF the edited row is between firstdatarow and the last row
  // AND
  // IF the edited column is Column#1  (Column A)
  // AND
  // IF the edited sheet is Master
  if (firstdatarow <= editRow && editRow <= masterLR && editColumn == 1 && e.value == "Y" && editSheet == mastername) {

    // do something
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: do something");

    // get the employee name
    var empname = masterData[(+editRow-4)][0];
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: The employee name is "+empname);


    // create an alert to confirm
    var result = ui.alert(
      'WARNING!!  You are about to Update the holiday record for '+empname,
      'Are you sure you want to continue?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

    // Process the user's response.
    if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
      // User clicked "Yes".
      ui.alert('Confirmation received.');


      // build the data to be pasted to Sheet5
      var holsData = [];
      for (var i = 1; i<54;i++){ 
        for (var x = 1; x<8;x++){
          holsData.push(masterData[(+editRow-4)][x]);
        }
        //Logger.log("DEBUG: hols = "+holsData+", length = "+holsData.length);
      }
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: Progressive holsData = "+holsData+", length = "+holsData.length);


      // create the range for Sheet5
      var target = hols.getRange(editRow,2,1,(+holsLC-1));
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: the target range = "+target.getA1Notation());

      // update the values to Sheet5
      target.setValues([holsData]);

      //Removes "Y" to stop code repeating
      master.getRange(editRow,editColumn).clearContent();


    } else {

      // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
      ui.alert('Permission denied.');

      //Removes "Y" to stop code repeating
      master.getRange(editRow,editColumn).clearContent(); 
    }
  }
  else
  {
    // don't do anything
    Logger.log("don't do anything");
  }  
}
```

Comment: Hi I get the following error  var editColumn = e.range.getColumn(); the error message says Type error:Cannot read property "Range" form yndefined (line 29,File "code"

Comment: That's the error that you get when you run an `onEdit(e)` function manually (from the Script Editor). onEdit is designed to run when a user changes a value in a spreadsheet [Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) and [Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). Click "Dismiss" to get rid of the error message, then jump over to Sheet4 of the spreadsheet and type "Y" (caps) in Column A beside one of the employee names.

Comment: Hi thank you very much that is working great.  I have a piece of code I will use often.  Clearly I have a lot to learn but I can move on now with the rest of what I need to do.  Thanks again for all your help Col